# SSRS Report table formatting

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I've been trying to get the grouping down for this report to show the location above each of the invoices for the different locations, but I can't get it to show every item in the invoice and every location at once, it's one or the other.

[image: Where the 595 sits is what I am trying to recreate but I can't find the right grouping.]

Anyone know how to group it with the name and the invoice number to show what I'm describing?

I've tried grouping the invoice to the customer's name and vise versa.

Comment: I think you need to knock up an example, in say Excel, to illustrate what you are trying to accomplish because its not clear to me.

Comment: Please show a small sample of your data and the expected outcome. It's not clear from your question what you are expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description, it sounds like you may be including the name and location in the Detail row.  When a field is in a Parent or Child Group above the Details, there is usually no need to include it also among the fields in the detail row.

If you want to, you can combine more than one field in a group.  In Group Properties, you can do something like this:

[image: Example of using two fields in a Group]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, it sounds like you need more than one grouping level.

If you want to use a TABLIX, not a MATRIX, I'd suggest that you make a Parent Level Group (Add a header) containing the Location field.
Then, under the Location Group, make a Child Level Group (Add a header) containing the Customer Name.
Then, right click the Customer Name Group and make a Child Level Group containing the Invoice Number.
In the Details row, you should include fields for all of the data required for each row of the invoice.

Hopefully, this will help to get you started.
If you provide more information, I'll do what I can to get you there.

Comment: So, what I'm trying to achieve is having the name and location in one cell above the invoices per location as a kind of header but when I try to group by invoice it splits each item up and repeats the name and location with it, but I only want it to show once as a header per invoice so I want to get them not in the same row but stacked on top of each other. I hope that makes more sense.